# UIImageView null when updated with Timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, uiimageview, uiimage

I am currently trying to update a series of UIImageViews using a timer. The method **updateNavBar** is being called from another class every one second, and checks a series of conditions. The conditions are being met (verified in debugger and print statements), but when I try to update the image the UIImageView (such as img1) is null:

```
img2: (null)
```

However, the image views can be assigned with content in the viewDidLoad:

```
img2: <UIImageView: 0x7bf61930; frame = (250 42; 119 106); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf619e0>>
```

updateNavBar code:

```
-(void) updateNavBar:(int)updateValue
{
    UIImage *viewActive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"storySelected.png"];
    UIImage *defaultState = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blank.png"];

    if (updateValue == 1)
    {
        [Img1 setImage:viewActive];
        NSLog(@"Is img1 null?: %@", img1);

    }
    if (updateValue == 2)
    {
        [Img2 setImage:defaultState];
        NSLog(@"Is img2 null?: %@", img2);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is 'statusImg2' ? You could just print Img2.

Comment: Sorry - typing error on my behalf, was trying to make variables more understandable - now updated

Comment: can you make sure that the updateNavBar method is called after the viewDidLoad? (with logs for instance)

Comment: If Img2 is NOT null in viewDidLoad, but is null later, you should just watch out for assignments to that variable. If you are using a property (which you should anyway) you could just overWrite -(void)setImg2:(UIImageView *)imgaView method and set a breakpoint in there to debug the setter calls

Comment: Where exactly is the timer started?

Comment: img2 is a UIImageView in the interface builder and is a property:
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Img2;

Comment: And I have a timer class which is started when the previous view didDisappear. This then calls the method in another view controller (which works).

Comment: It appears to be the fact that is being called from another class. I am calling the view controller from the timer class, something like:

[myViewController updateNavBar:2]

When I have a timer actually IN my class, the object is NOT null.